# Dropdown Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

I have code to Open a URL in new tab but it opens the url in new window and when i refresh the main page it reopen the previous url selected from dropdownlist.I want to open the url in new tab and stop to reopen the selcted url again my code is below

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("var w = window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num=26');", DropDownList1.SelectedValue), True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping you are opening the url in a button click. Include the following line in the markup code of the button to open the url in a new tab/window. Refer to this [link](http://www.waytocoding.com/2011/02/open-url-in-new-tab-using.html) for more information.

```
OnClientClick=”aspnetForm.target =’_blank’;”
```

EDIT:

Refer to the following code part may be its useful to you

```
 protected void ddlAuthoritytype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var port = Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port.ToString();

        string ddl = ddlAuthoritytype.SelectedValue;
        switch (ddl)
        {
            case "AL":
                var script = string.Format("window.open('{0}://{1}{2}{3}')", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, port, ResolveUrl("~/alabama-state-tax-calculator.aspx"));
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow",script, true);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No SIr i have dropdownlist to open the url

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("var w = window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num={0}','_blank');", DropDownList1.SelectedValue), True)